# What does the 'amplification factor' of gravitational microlensing mean?

Tags: gravitational-lensing

At first I assumed the amplification factor meant an increase in brightness. But since the equation: $$A(u)=\frac{u^2+2}{u\sqrt{u^2+4}}$$ is independent of mass, this make no sense to me. Wouldn't everything be infinity magnified (if its mass independent empty space should work, right)? Even if its simply not valid for a zero mass, everything would be amplified by an arbitrarily high amount any time even a neutrino passes arbitrarily close to the right $u$?
But if its not brightness, I don't know what signal is being amplified.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia page explains this pretty clearly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gravitational lensing is just geometry, as is optical lensing. The amplification factor describes the increase of the **area** of the image (at constant surface brightness).

BTW, the amplification factor *does* depend on the mass $M$ of the lens, since $u=\theta/\theta_E$ and $\theta_E$ depends on $M$. Here $\theta$ and $\theta_E$ are the relative angular distance between source and lens and the radius (angle) of the Einstein ring for the lens, respectively.

Comment: I think it is the second part here that answers the question. You could explain what theta and theta_E represent. A picture of the geometry would be even better.